# The distribution of sample proportion for given population proportion and sample size

Tags: probability-distributions, sampling

> If the population proportion is 0.90 and a sample of size 64 is taken, what is the probability that the sample proportion is more than 0.89? (4dp)

work: $n=64$,  $\hat p=0.89$, so $X=n \hat p =56.96$. 
$$ P(\hat p >0.89)=P( X >56.95)=1- P( X <56.95)$$
      and then how to do it?

The answer is $0.6064$

More details of the solutions would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since $np > 10$ we can apply Central Limit Theorem and use the formula $\mathbb{P}\!\left(p < \hat{p}\right)= \mathbb{P}\!\left(Z<\frac{p-\hat{p}}{s}\right)$ where $s = \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$ and $Z \sim N(0,1)$.

My answer came out to be .6052 (I didn't use a standard normal table).

Comment: it should be the np≥5  and then the sampling distribution of the sample proportion p-hat is approximately normally distributed.

Comment: thanks. i have figure it out. here: P[Z<(p-p^)/SD]=P[Z<(0.9-0.89)/√(0.9*0.1)/64]=P(Z<0.27)

Comment: @Hiver I think that condition varies depending on how your taught. But my guess is both are right. Anyways, you can still accept my answer, if you wish.